# Conflito com a <meta name="viewport"

Tags: php, html

Olá, estou tendo problema com a `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`, pois tenho esse código abaixo:

```
     <div style="max-width:30px; width:100%; z-index:99999999;" class="social_bar">
        <style>
        .social{
            display:block;
            width:30px;
            height:30px;
                <?php
                $icones = $_POST['icones'];
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pagcabecalho");
                $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                ?>
            background-image: url(img/<?php echo $res['icones']; ?>.png);
            float:left;
            margin-left:4px;
            overflow:hidden;
            text-indent:-999px;
            margin-bottom:4px;
        }

        .social_bar{
            margin-top:-100px;
            position:fixed;
            right: 7px;
            top: 50%;
            width: 40px;
            z-index:9999;
            float:left;
        }

        #contato_dt{ background-position: 0 0; z-index:999999999;}  
        #instagram_dt{ background-position:-32px 0; z-index:999999999;} 
        #facebook_dt{ background-position:-64px 0; z-index:999999999;}
        #twitter_dt{ background-position:-96px 0; z-index:999999999;}
        #youtube_dt{ background-position:-128px 0; z-index:999999999;}
        </style>
        <?php
        $endtwitter = $_POST['endtwitter'];
        $endface = $_POST['endface'];
        $endyoutube = $_POST['endyoutube'];
        $endinstagram = $_POST['endinstagram'];

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pagcabecalho");
        $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        ?>
        <?php echo $res['linkcontato']; ?>
        <?php echo $res['linkinstagram']; ?>
        <?php echo $res['linktwitter']; ?>
        <?php echo $res['linkface']; ?>
        <?php echo $res['linkyoutube']; ?>
    </div>
```

que direciona para as páginas referentes a cada rede social selecionada.

Porem, quando a `<meta name="viewport"` esta habilitada os ícones não se tornam responsivos, já quando retiro-a eles ficam responsivos.

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda ou mesmo uma dica de como fazer com que os ícones ser tornem responsivo com a `<meta name="viewport"`.

Imagens com e sem a `<meta name="viewport"` no código.

Com a `<meta name="viewport"`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sem a `<meta name="viewport"`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Define um width para o background no css
background-size:cover
Creio que isso te ajudará.

Comment: Width, não. Define o size.

Comment: Valeu pela a dica @Vítor André, mas eu inseri o `background-size:cover` ao style mas não resolveu. E descobri que quando eu retiro a `<meta name="viewport"`, os ícones ficam responsivos, porém perco o efeito do `Toggle navigation`. estou postando imagens com e sem a `<meta name="viewport"` para que você possa ver o que acontece, valeu?

Comment: Vou postar as imagens na pergunta, OK? Abraços e desde já meus agradecimentos.

Comment: Eu acredito que eles não estejam, de fato, responsivos sem o view, pois você não utiliza medida em % e sim medida fixa (em px) tanto para a barra quanto para os icones.

Ponha uma medida em percentual e veja como fica.

Se não for isso, talvez tenha algum css que esteja entrando e desfazendo o teu efeito desejado @Murilo Cabral